# regexp_like that mirrors contains near

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-text, regexp-like

I'm trying to speed up a query that uses Contains Near with one that uses regexp_like.  The initial Contains Near query takes about 45 minutes to run.  Clob Column holds large "documents" and is domain indexed.

**Initial query:**

```
SELECT column1
FROM TEST
WHERE CONTAINS(column1,'{NEAR(quick,fox, lazy), 3, FALSE}')>0;
```

**Proposed query:**

```
SELECT column1
FROM TEST
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(column1, '(\b(quick|fox|lazy)(?:\W+\w+){1,6}?\W(quick|fox|lazy)(?:\W+\w+){1,}?\W(quick|fox|lazy)\b)','i')
```

I got the original regexp syntax from here:
https://www.regular-expressions.info/near.html.

**Problem:**
I get the regexp code to work in html https://www.regextester.com, but when I put it in Oracle it doesn't find anything.  What is wrong with my syntax?  I can't figure it out.   Does Oracle handle REGEXP differently?

Comment: [Oracle doesn't support all regex flavours and extensions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Oracle-Regular-Expression-Support.html#GUID-969230D6-FC1A-4C75-BF2A-6B1BE909DED6). I think it's the `?:`  that's tripping you up, but not sure. I'm a bit surprised a regular expression would be faster though...

Comment: To find a single word you need to use `REGEXP_LIKE(column1, '[[:blank:]](quick|fox|lazy)[[:blank:]]','i')`.

Comment: @AlexPoole, I am not sure if it is quicker.  I am just tasked to find a quicker way and was going to check this out.  They use both CONTAINS and REGEXP_LIKE a lot

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I want, ideally,

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I want, ideally:
Find the document that has these 3 words and each word has maximum of 1-6 words between each of them.  They can be in any order.  I can find documents with one of these using regexp, but can't seem to duplicate what I can do with contains near using regexp in Oracle, only outside of Oracle.

Comment: Can anyone think of a better way to speed up the CONTAINS/NEAR code in ORACLE? I'm at a loss.

Comment: My point was to use `[[:blank:]]` and **NOT** `\b` that doesn't match.

Comment: Can you describe your setup in a bit detail. Do you have a [library of Alexandria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_of_Alexandria) that it takes 45 minutes to scan? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex, you were exactly right.  I don't see how to select your answer as correct though.

My problem was apparently that I was using regexp parameters that Oracle doesn't recognize.  So, whereas it worked on https://www.regextester.com, it failed to work in Oracle because most of what I used isn't recognized as usable with regexp in Oracle.  I really think Oracle should expand their  regexp codes it recognized.  This was really frustrating.